# How do I dynamically include the backing bean value in jsf 1.2

Tags: jsf, tomahawk, jspinclude, backing-beans

Hi i have the following code

creatPage1.jsp

```
<h:inputText id="inputId1" value="#{createPage.item.name}"/>
```

i have updatePage1.jsp

```
<h:inputText id="inputId1" value="#{updatePage.item.name}"/>
```

I want to be able to do include (via ui:include or jsp:include) and be able to pass in the value dynamically (the base backing bean to be createPage or updatePage).

So the result should be

```
<ui:include src="Page1.jsp" basebean="#{createPage}"/>
```

Page1.jsp

```
<h:inputText id="inputId1" value="#{baseBean.item.name}"/>
```

Whats the best way to do this in jsf?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ui:param` :

```
<ui:include src="Page1.jsp">
  <ui:param name="basebean" value="#{createPage}"/>
</ui:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to create your own custom tag. Check this out: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/